# Not able to scrape data in "div" class on WSJ pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape text content from articles on the WSJ site. For e.g. consider the following html source:

```
<div class="article-content ">
       <p>BEIRUT—
      Carlos Ghosn, 
       who is seeking to clear his name in Lebanon, would face a very different path to vindication here, where endemic corruption and the former auto executive’s widespread popularity could influence the outcome of a potential trial. </p> <p>Mr. Ghosn, the former chief of auto makers
```

I am using the following code:

```
res = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
classid = "article-content "
item = html.find_all("div", {"class":classid})
```

This returns a null item. I saw a few other posts where people have suggested [adding delays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898460/not-able-to-scrape-data-using-beautifulsoup) and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100398/beautifulsoup-returning-none-when-element-definitely-exists) but these are not working in my case. Plan on using the scraped text for some ML projects.

I have a subscription to WSJ and am logged in when running the above script.

Any help with this will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: turn off javascript in the browser and reload the page. Is the content you want still present?

Comment: Yes, checked both the rendered page and the html source.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me. Just make sure that you are searching for the correct 'classid'. I don't think this will make a difference, but you can try using this as an alternative:

```
item = html.find_all("div", class_ = classid)
```

Comment: Thanks Sultan. Just doesn't work at my end: html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
classid = "article-content " #there's a space after the last t 
item = html.find_all("div", class_ = classid)
print(item). Output is "[]"

Comment: Can you try classid = "article" and see what happens??

Comment: Same. :( Possible for you to share a screenshot of code and output? Many thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can be done is to confirm the presence of the element by checking with javascript on the console. Many a times there are background requests being made to serve the page. So, you might see the element in the page..but it is the result of a request to different URL or inside of a script.

Comment: Thanks. That is what's happening. I searched the output of html and could not find the tag so it's being generated dynamically. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: @user6027414 I don't have subscription to WSJ..so I cannot check..however, You can try searching for ('script')..If the article is generated by a script ..it will show up..then you need to use json.loads. If you feel the answer helped, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `select` and set the parser as 'lxml'

```
content = [p.text for p in soup.select('.article-content p')]
```